# Is it possible to create a CSS-only accordion?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, accordion

I'm thinking about using an accordion in a "please enable Javascript" page, but I don't know if it's possible with **CSS only**.

I'm almost sure it is for most browsers, but I'm also fearing I'll face some limitation of IE and I'd like to know if any of you tried this already (or not) and could tell me if it's either *possible* or *impossible* (considering IE6+).

Comment: What type of according you need , can you show and example?

Comment: A very simple one would do, something like this for example: http://www.brown.edu/ but without necessarily a transition. What I want with this is not to scare the user with a long page with many headers, instead just letting them click on their browser's step-by-step instruction to enabling JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some CSS only Accordin here

http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/05/17/8-powerful-pure-css-accordions-to-make-web-application-lite-and-impressive/

And it is IE 6 compatible

http://www.cssnewbie.com/advanced-css-accordion-effect/

http://www.cssnewbie.com/example/css-only-accordion/vertical.html

Comment: +1 since it's almost what I need but, quoting the site, "will function in IE6 with JavaScript". So it won't work if my intention is to ask IE6 users to enable JS too, but actually I don't think IE6 users even know how to disable it.

Comment: it works even if js disabled http://www.cssnewbie.com/example/css-only-accordion/vertical.html

Comment: And BTW it's ok if Accordion work if JS enabled and if JS disabled then According will be open by default. as in this link http://www.brown.edu/ . main thing is content should accessible in both condition.

Comment: Yes, you're right. That's enough for IE6 and it works as wanted in others. Good finding! :)

Answer (score -1):

It is impossible without JavaScript. Even if you use the new HTML5 transitions (which are certainly not supported in IE6), you still need JavaScript to trigger the transition.

Comment: You're wrong, CSS transitions (supported in latest webkit, beta gecko and AFAIK stable presto) can be used solely with CSS. And I recommend you to use them, take a look: http://u.nu/7avrc